# SQL Converting table -> changing repeating attributes into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, oracle, woocommerce

I'm creating a site using WooCommerce and I would like to integrate it with my warehouse.

I need to convert a table that looks like that:

```
   ----------------------------
id |post_id| meta_key|meta_value |
   ----------------------------
 1 | 1     |_stock   |1          |
 2 | 1     |_price   |10         |
 3 | 1     |X        |X          |
 4 | 2     |_stock   |2          |
 5 | 2     |_price   |8          |
 6 | 2     |X        |X          |
```

into:

```
   -------------------------
   |post id|_stock | _price  |
   -------------------------
   | 1     |1      |10       |
   | 2     |2      |8        |
```

I tried:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value AS stock
FROM wp_postmeta
JOIN
(
SELECT post_id, meta_value AS regular_price
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
)
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock'
ORDER BY post_id ASC
```

and got:

> '#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Is there any way that avoids `create table`?

I've just started my adventure with sql and sorry if the answer is obvious. And sorry if the title is misleading.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: As you are using a subquery on the same table, a _table alias_ (soft renaming) is wanted for unique column references: `SELECT w.post_id FROM wp_postmeta AS w` (`AS` is optional, `w` is the alias). What you are doing is called a [**pivot table**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select post_id,
       max(case when meta_key = '_stock' then meta_value end) as stock,
       max(case when meta_key = '_regular_price' then meta_value end) as regular_price
from wp_postmeta
where meta_key in ('_stock', '_regular_price')
group by post_id;
```

Comment: You are great.

Thank You so much!

Comment: Excuse me @Gordon Linoff, why are you using the `max`, not the `sum`?

Comment: @D-Shih . . . The value is a string, so `sum()` might not work.  In addition, I think there should only be one value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I got it,Thank you :)